# Hyperledger Fabric - NodeJS SDK Query Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm not able to query the chaincode with multiple peers associated to one channel.

I have created a chaincode which exposes a query method.

Using the NodeJS SDK, I'm able to successfully invoke it when I configure the channel with only one peer.

```
var peer1 = fabric_client.newPeer(url,{pem: pem});
channel.addPeer(peer1)
```

But when I try to invoke the method with two peers associate to the channel, I don't get any answer from the chaincode.

```
var peer1 = fabric_client.newPeer(url1,{pem: pem1});
var peer2 = fabric_client.newPeer(url2,{pem: pem2});

channel.addPeer(peer1);
channel.addPeer(peer2);

var requestQuery = {
    chaincodeId: chaincode, //chaincode name
    fcn: fcn, // chaincode method
    args: args //arguments
};

var query_responses = await channel.queryByChaincode(request);
```

Do you know why with two peers is not working?

Comment: you will need to provide much more context before we can answer your question. What error are you seeing? Also, it is unclear from your code snippet, but you cannot use the same certificates for multiple peers. Nor would they have the same address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I have modified the code snippet. 
When the channel has two peers associated,  I don't get any answer if I query the chaincode.

Comment: Hi May I know is it working for one peer. Because for one peer also is not working for me in windows visual studio code editor.